# How to install JRE 1.7 on Mac OS X and use it with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, macos, java

I want to use the JRE 1.7 that I downloaded [from Oracle website](http://java.com/fr/download/mac_download.jsp?locale=fr).

So I correctly install the .pkg file, and when I try `/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java -version` in the terminal I get this :

> java version "1.7.0_11" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.7.0_11-b21) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)

But in Eclipse I can't use anything else than JRE 1.6. When I go in Properties > Java Build Path > Add Library > JRE System Library, I can't find the 1.7 (there is only option for it : `JavaSE-1.7 (unbound)` with this issue :

> No JREs in workspace compatible with specified execution environment: JavaSE-1.7

What should I do ? Thanks

Comment: Did you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7842967/1277252)?

Comment: This was exactly the same question I had. Ian Roberts's answer solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be a pretty common problem.  Why on Earth would you close it?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The download from `java.com` which installs in `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins` is only the JRE, for development you probably want to download the JDK from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html and install that instead.  This will install the JDK at `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_<something>.jdk/Contents/Home` which you can then add to Eclipse via Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs.

Comment: Thanks, in Eclipse Kepler Project>Properties>Java Build Path>Add Library>JRE System Library>Installed JREs>Add and worked with e.g.: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: Also! When adding an installed JRE to Eclipse, Eclipse can also "search" for installed JREs. That's how I got Eclipse to connect to my existing installation of 1.7 JDK.

Comment: OH WOW! I spent about 4 hours on this... I installed like 3 different Eclipse's, Java 1.7 and 1.8... all it took was a damn "search" button !!

Comment: For some reason, Java 1.6 was installed under /System/Library on my machine, but the Oracle installer put 1.7 under simply /Library.  Kind of threw me at first, and the Search... button didn't find the 1.7 install.  FYI.

Comment: @Marvo yes, only software from Apple is allowed to install itself under `/System`. Third-party software (which includes Oracle Java) has to go elsewhere.

Comment: Actually, the jdk download I just installed appears to have updated the java executable at /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java. It now reports version "1.8.0_25" compared to 1.6 from a few minutes ago.

Comment: @MatthewBrown the `java` command in Versions/Current/Commands (and the one in /usr/bin) is a stub that delegates to whichever JDK your `JAVA_HOME` points to, or the most up to date one you have installed if `JAVA_HOME` is not set. The actual 1.8 JDK has installed into /Library/Java

Comment: Go to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html and download Java SE Development Kit 8u91

Answer (score 8):

Try editing your eclipse.ini file and add the following at the top

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Of course the path may be slightly different, looks like I have an older version...

I'm not sure if it will add itself automatically. If not go into

Preferences --> Java --> Installed JREs

Click Add and follow the instructions there to add it

Comment: Thank you for this. I am really surprised how tough it is to find information on installing and using java. Coming from other open source projects back to using java for now, I am very used to an active, engaged community providing tons of useful information.

Comment: It worked with '/Library/java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/contents/Home/bin' , not this one : '/Library/java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/contents/Home'

Answer (score 7):

You need to tell Eclipse which JDK/JRE's you have installed and where they are located.

This is somewhat burried in the Eclipse preferences: In the Window-Menu select "Preferences". In the Preferences Tree, open the Node "Java" and select "Installed JRE's". Then click on the "Add"-Button in the Panel and select "Standard VM", "Next" and for "JRE Home" click on the "Directory"-Button and select the top level folder of the JDK you want to add.

Its easier than the description may make it look.