# Installed JDK 7 but it is not appearing in my JavaVirtualMachines folder

Tags: java-7, java

Anyone know what the problem is?

I recently downloaded and installed JDK 7u21, but when I went to add the JRE to eclipse, I did not find it in the JavaVirtualMachines folder, all that was there was 1.6.0 JDK

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install JRE 1.7 on Mac OS X and use it with Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341865/how-to-install-jre-1-7-on-mac-os-x-and-use-it-with-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't set `CLASSPATH`,`JAVA_HOME` into Environment variable?

and set jdk path into System variable `Path`

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are two `JavaVirtualMachines` folders on your system:

- `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` is where the default Apple 1.6 JDK/JRE is installed
- `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` is where all other JDK's (such as those from Oracle) are installed

If you only install the JRE (as opposed to the JDK), it will most likely end up in the `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home` directory.