# ADT can't find installed JREs on Mac

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I have ADT Installed. v23.0.2. 
I tried to import simple java project, but found no installed JRE to compile the code. I then installed JDK & JRE from Java SE downloads. I yet don't see any JRE in the list. Anything am I missing? any hooks ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it does not find it "automagically" then you need to "Add" it or "Search" it. Most likely though, when you installed the JRE, it was not properly added to the "path" or another install problem.

See this post:

[How to install JRE 1.7 on Mac OS X and use it with Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341865/how-to-install-jre-1-7-on-mac-os-x-and-use-it-with-eclipse)

Chances are "Search" will do what you need.

Comment: The search didn't work, which was strange to me too. I explicitly added the Home path of java, which then solved the problem. Thanks for your answer though.