# Can't start Eclipse on OSX (Version not suitable)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I just tried to run Eclipse on a Mac Book Pro running OSX Mavericks. I've downloaded both, the 32 and the 64 bit version. Both end up in following Notification:

```
Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product.
  Version: 1.7 or greater is required.
```

I know that the question was already asked, but my Eclipse won't event start with the 64-bit version, which was the answer for a smiliar question. So I checked the version of my installed Java by running

```
java -version
```

In the terminal. The output really confirmed, that version 1.6.0_65 was installed. Here's the output:

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

Now the problem is that when launching the Java Control panel, it says, that Java 7 Update 67 is installed, and there are no updates.

So where's my problem, how get I get Eclipse to run?

Answer (score 1):

You can [`modify the eclipse.ini`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) and add the path to your JDK7

> For versions of Mac OS X 10.7+ the location has changed to

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<''jdk_name_ver''>/Contents/Home/...
```

> To be safer, determine the location for the JDK you intend to use via the utility `/usr/libexec/java_home` and put this value with `.../bin/java` appended into the `eclipse.ini` file.

See "[How to install JRE 1.7 on Mac OS X and use it with Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14342646/6309)"

Answer (score 0):

I installed JDK, "Java SE Development Kit 8u101", in addition to JRE and eclipse started to work fine.