# After install jdk 7u67, I have error when creating new Android project

Tags: java, android

My ADT works well before I install JDK 7u67. But after install that, I have error like this when creating new Android project :

**Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'Ders'.
java.lang.NullPointerException**

This is the error after creating new android project :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In eclipse when you install different version of java,it does not change the working `JRE`.You must change it by `Window-Preferences-Java-BuildPath` or `Window-Preferences-Java-InstalledJre`

Comment: My eclipse in mac. I confuse how to add JRE, I have searched 'jre' in search box then I don't find it

Comment: you can look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341865/how-to-install-jre-1-7-on-mac-os-x-and-use-it-with-eclipse

Comment: Now you can make project clean.After that it must work.

Comment: After cleaning, I don't see error message. But after I create new project again, still error...