# How to save user name (simple example of jdbc) in java?

Tags: java, jdbc

can you please give the steps how to make simple program of jdbc on mac .

I have eclipse on my mac .so I need steps what to do next so that can able to make program of jdbc ?
I do lot of RND but they provide for windows.But I also download Mysql from this link
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=450342
and download workbench from this link 
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=412161

Then can you please may I right ?
or what next I have to do to make jdbc program ?

Comment: I found lot of example for window

Comment: But I need for mac ..how to configure mysql with eclipse .I will make program but I need initial steps

Comment: what exactly doesn't apply to mac which is working on windows?

Comment: Actually I am beginner in java .recently I run my dng files of mysql .It work fine .But now how to connect with my eclipse after running mysql server

Comment: searching for hello world mysql java should show you some tutorials

Comment: can you please tell I need only  mysqlserver ? or I need workbench also

Answer (score 0):

There is not much difference at all in using a Mac than other platforms for working with JDBC.

## JDK

You need an implementation of Java, a "JDK". See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10358228/642706) to another question about installing Java 7 and Java 8 on a Mac, including links for downloading a JDK. Before doing the database stuff, be sure this works in the [Terminal.app](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_%28OS_X%29) program: `java -version`

## JDBC Driver

You need a [JDBC driver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) specific to your particular database engine.

## H2 Database

I suggest trying the [H2 database](http://www.h2database.com) rather than MySQL, only because it may be a gentler easier way to get started. H2 is pure Java, rather simple in terms of installing and administrating, and free-of-cost. H2 comes with its own JDBC driver. The H2 web site has a quick-start page and a tutorial page. It is not written explicitly for Mac OS X, but you should be able to "translate" as needed.

## Oracle Tutorial

Then follow the [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) provided by Oracle.

---

Also: StackOverflow is for *specific* questions on programming, not general or wide-ranging discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Install and start MySql.

Download the MySql JDBC driver.  Try here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/.  Extract all the files and add the jar to your eclipse project.

Now you can start coding.  Look up the docs for DriverManager, Statement and ResultSet.

Comment: There is option of platform and independent which I have to doenload

Comment: platform independent.  i think other one is for windows