# How to set the JAVA_HOME in Mavericks 10.9?

Tags: java, tomcat, osx-mavericks, workspace

I checked the java it is installed on my system.If i enter `whereis java` it shows me the

```
/usr/bin/java
```

I want to set the `JAVA_HOME`, i already gave the path `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home` but it won't work.

If i enter `$JAVA_HOME` it returns nothing.

1. If i enter this command `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7` it shows me the result

   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home

but while setting up my local workspace it won't work it simply says

```
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home` is not valid `JAVA_HOME`
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267392/how-do-i-use-jdk-7-on-mac-osx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment variables such as this are stored in bash and users use configuration files to set parameters for their bash environments.

for example in your home directory you will likely have one or both of a .bashrc or a .bash_profile file.

1) open this file

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

2) add the following line to this file

```
#Default to java 1.6
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6`
```

This will set the $JAVA_HOME variable to the path defined above.  In my case:

```
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Once you change a bash configuration file you either need to restart your terminal or source that file

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Then finally confirm that this worked by running the command

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: You need back ticks otherwise it will save the string as the environment variable.  Also the spaces will throw erros

Comment: There are back ticks in the answer... and I tested it with the spaces and they work as long as they are contained within the back ticks

Comment: @pwilmot Yep! I think it was because of the original formatting they didn't show up.  Looks good now!

Comment: @AdalarasanSachithanantham after following the steps when you enter echo $JAVA_HOME into a terminal nothing shows up?

Comment: once i followed the steps it shows me the path..but if i close the terminal and open it again...It doesn't shows anything.