# How to install Java 8 on Mac

Tags: java, macos, java-8, installation

Editors note:  This question was asked in 2014, and the answers may be outdated.

---

I want to do some programming with the latest JavaFX, which requires Java 8. I'm using IntelliJ 13 CE and Mac OS X 9 Mavericks. I ran Oracle's Java 8 installer, and the files look like they ended up at

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk
```

but previous versions are at

```
/System/Library/Java/JavaFrameworks/jdk1.6....
```

Not sure why the latest installer puts this in `/Library` instead of `/System/Library` (nor what the difference is). But `/usr/libexec/java_home` doesn't find 1.8, so all the posts I've found on how to set your current java version don't work. I've tried adding a symbolic link to make it look like 1.8 is in the `/System/Library...` path, but it doesn't help. `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` still only lists the old Java 1.6.

Ironically, the "Java" control panel under System Preferences shows only Java 1.8!

Why doesn't Oracle's installer put it where it really goes? And how can I work around this problem?

Comment: It "really goes" where it ended up -- `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/`. The previous one was where the Apple-provided Java versions went, and as Apple doesn't provide Java any more the install location has changed.

Comment: Similar: [*How to use jdk without jre in Java 11*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52584888/642706)

Comment: brew install openjdk@8

Comment: brew install --cask temurin8 # Temurin is the official successor to adoptopenjdk

Comment: Update on 2022/8:  install it with " brew install --build-from-source openjdk@8"

Comment: As of 2022/09:  OpenJDK Java 8 installer is available from Eclipse Temurin project - https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/?version=8 .  This does not require homebrew installed.

Answer (score 2262):

Oracle has a poor record for making it easy to install and configure Java, but using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), the latest OpenJDK (Java 14) can be installed with:

```
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk8
```

For the many use cases depending on an older version (commonly Java 8), the [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) project makes it possible with an extra step.

```
brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk8
```

Existing users of Homebrew may encounter `Error: Cask adoptopenjdk8 exists in multiple taps` due to prior workarounds with different instructions. This can be solved by fully specifying the location with `brew install --cask adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8`.

Comment: I had to run this multiple times before the the dmg would download from oracle, each time it continued at the last point it left off.

Comment: @James - was probably a network issue. +1 for mentioning jenv

Comment: As of December 2015, it is now unnecessary to install cask manually as it is now part of homebrew's installation. So after updating homebrew via `brew update`, you are set to use `brew cask`.

Comment: Thanks, it's amazing how horrible the Java installation process using the "official" links/docs are.

Comment: @l3x - I suggested an edit that would update your answer to what davetw12 said.  It was rejected because reviewers felt it was too different from your answer.  Would you be willing to make your answer a shared answer so we can make this right and current?  Or otherwise accept the edit?

Comment: @tandrewnichols I just ran `brew cask install java` on my El Capitan Mac and it's downloading `jdk-8u112-macosx-x64.dmg`.

Comment: If having anymore issue with JRE or JDK try https://gist.github.com/johan/10590467

Comment: it DOES install JDK. `brew cask info java`

Comment: In contrast to @tandrewnichols I found this procedure installed JDK as well as the runtime - so full Java support.

Comment: If you installed java using the Oracle updater and want Homebrew to manage it, do I have to fully uninstall the Oracle Java first?

Comment: ```brew cask install java``` installed jdk ftw

Comment: Note that as of October 2017, the default brew command (as well as most of those in the comments) will install whatever is the *latest* major version JDK (i.e. java 9) rather than a specific older one (for example, Java 8 as in the OP). See this helpful blog post for a description of how to use brew to install an earlier version of Java if needed. http://www.lonecpluspluscoder.com/2017/10/08/installing-other-versions-of-the-java-jdk-via-homebrew/

Comment: What is cask significance here ?

Comment: In case others missed this, the `brew cask install java8` approach installs `java` in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`.

Comment: 3/28/18 - try:  brew install caskroom/version/java8

Comment: `Error: Cask 'java8' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.`

Comment: I had to use the following commands `brew tap homebrew/cask-versions; brew cask install java8`

Comment: What happens if I install java via brew, and java was already installed from some other method? Will brew handle this ok? Or do I need to explicitly uninstall first?

Comment: `brew cask install java8`  
Error: Cask java8 exists in multiple taps:

Comment: @danvk I install brew under ~/homebrew and hope the java can be installed under the ~/homebrew/bin, just like other apps, do you think it's possible and how to do that?

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, see [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions/issues/7253) for more details.

Comment: @WeiChingLin you can fix that by specifying which tap you want to install from. e.g. `brew cask install caskroom/versions/java8` or `brew cask install homebrew/cask-versions/java8`. However, that wont work currently since oracle is phasing out their java8 download. See [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions/issues/7253) for more details.

Comment: The workaround for now is to `brew tap homebrew/cask-versions` and use `brew cask install homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8`

Comment: It is not possible to install Java8 using Brew anymore because of Oracle license changes. Java8 is not public anymore for download.

Comment: See [this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55774255/9348376) for further details.

Comment: Java8 is not available for brew / cask anymore: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions/issues/7253

Comment: `Cask 'java8' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.`

Comment: Why not rely on the Oracle installer?  Has worked for me so far.

Comment: Great advice to install jenv, makes it a lot easier to manage  several versions of java. I am always wary of zapping anything installed into macOS by Apple, and with jenv, you can keep everything nicely separated.

Comment: Latest workaround requires `brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk` followed by `brew cask install adoptopenjdk8`. That may fail with "Error: Cask adoptopenjdk8 exists in multiple taps" because you already attempted this another way, so specify exact location with `brew cask install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8`

Comment: Ran these commands, but the wrong version of openjdk is on my machine: ```java --version```

```openjdk 12.0.1 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 12.0.1+12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)```

Comment: If you have multiple versions of open jdk installed and want to change default version: `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` and then `export JAVA_HOME='usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_232'` used example version

Comment: On reinstall I had to enter my password 300 times for it to reinstall properly - I guess I needed to give permission to overwrite a bunch of existing files.

Comment: `brew cask remove java; brew cask install adoptopenjdk8; java -version`

Comment: `openJDK` does not contain JavaFX

Comment: After following these steps, you may still need to define JAVA_HOME so it points to the brew installed java8.  What worked for me was `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)`

Comment: How to install specific build of AdoptOpenJdk8

Comment: `brew install --cask adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8` worked for me, I am on a mac Monterey with Apple M1 chip.

Comment: This answer appears to be out of date by now; other answers give more up-to-date instructions.

Comment: Error: `brew cask` is no longer a `brew` command. Use `brew <command> --cask` instead.


Using brew install --cask instead gives this error:


Error: Cask 'adoptopenjdk8' definition is invalid: 'appcast' stanza failed with: Calling the `appcast` stanza is disabled! Use the `livecheck` stanza instead.
Please report this issue to the adoptopenjdk/openjdk tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/homebrew-core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it:
  /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/adoptopenjdk/homebrew-openjdk/Casks/adoptopenjdk8.rb:9

Answer (score 874):

Note: Oracle Java 8/9/10 is no longer available for public download (license change).

First install and update ***brew*** from Terminal:

```
bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

brew tap homebrew/cask-versions

brew update
```

**NEW as of June 2019**

To install the JDKs from AdoptOpenJDK:

```
brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk

brew install --cask adoptopenjdk8
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk9
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk10
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk11
```

**OLD**

Java 8:

```
brew install --cask java8
```

Java Latest:

```bash
brew install --cask java
```

Comment: Interesting to note that this did not work for me on Mavericks, so it did not answer the OP's question, but it did work for me on Captain, so it was useful as an answer..

Comment: For me, in El Kapitan, it would only download a few extra percent each time I ran it, so I ran it in a loop (in fish shell) and it eventually worked.

`while math "$status == 1"; brew install Caskroom/cask/java; end`

Comment: This works, but I did have to `brew install Caskroom/cask/java` many times because the transfer kept closing: `curl: (18) transfer closed with 34724700 bytes remaining to read`

Comment: Didn't work for me on Yosemite (OSX v10.10.5). I get `Error: Cask 'java' definition is invalid: Bad header line: parse failed` ... Seems like this works only for El Capitan and not for any version preceding version of OSX (Yosemite, Mavericks..., )

Comment: I'm also getting the parse failed error, and I'm on El Capitan. Has anyone else encountered this and/or found a solution?

Comment: Oracle official site is giving weired errors, this is life savior

Comment: I installed homebrew fresh on a new OS X El Capitan machine and didn't have to run the `brew tap` command in the answer above. The first and third commands were sufficient.

Comment: brew cask install caskroom/versions/java8

Comment: Works on 10.8 after apple `git` is replaced with homebrew `git`. :) Very nice.

Comment: Anyone wanting Java 7: java7 is not available in cask versions, but zulu7 appears to work instead. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/9447

Comment: Error: Cask 'java8' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.

Comment: Use `brew tap caskroom/versions` before to avoid this errors. @Min2

Comment: On Mac OSX Sierra `brew cask install caskroom/versions/java8`

Comment: `curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Download failed on Cask 'java8' with message: Download failed: https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u192-b12/750e1c8617c5452694857ad95c3ee230/jdk-8u192-macosx-x64.dmg`

Comment: `Error: Cask 'java8' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.`

Comment: This worked perfectly in Aug 2019.

Steps:
1. `brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk`
2. `brew cask installadoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8`

Comment: `$ brew cask install adoptopenjdk8
Error: Cask adoptopenjdk8 exists in multiple taps:
  caskroom/versions/adoptopenjdk8
  adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8` .  I have to use `brew cask install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8`

Comment: just to follow from @roottraveller previous comment. It appears as though the adoptopenjdk versions are now in the caskroom/versions tap as well. So you could just do brew `tap caskroom/versions` and `brew cask install adoptopenjdk8`, skipping the adoptopenjdk tap. Might be useful if you've already tapped and updated caskroom/versions.

Comment: `brew tap homebrew/cask-versions` and `brew cask install adoptopenjdk8` works for me on Hi Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: Thank you for this. This also solves the error in Catalina " Java for macOS 2017-001 can’t be installed on a disk. A newer version of this package is already installed.".

Comment: @kavehmb Is there way to install it so without Sudo? Using above methods, it's trying to use `usr/local/` space, even when I specified `--appdir=~/Applications`?

Comment: how do i set the JAVA_HOME path for the openjdk8??

Comment: As @ kavehmb says, 1.$/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

$brew tap homebrew/cask-versions

$brew update

$brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk

$brew cask install homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8
(Or brew cask install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8)

That works for me on macOS 10.12.6 Sierra.

Comment: Adding this for people using newer mac versions

Warning: The Ruby Homebrew installer is now deprecated and has been rewritten in
Bash. Please migrate to the following command:
  /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

Comment: I believe the first command (to install "the latest OpenJDK") be
`brew install --cask adoptopenjdk` and not `brew install --cask adoptopenjdk8` which will install JSK 8 not latest? also the latest is now 15 (as of Sep 2020).
Also, Iit may help others to include `brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk` *before* the first command, as folks trying the install w/o the tap are getting errors.

Comment: What's the point to install adoptopenjdk8~adoptopenjdk11 at one time?

Comment: damn this was never this easy even on windows! no path setting, Android Studio ready right after just install. Best ever Java install on a new machine, specially Mac!

Comment: Your first sentence is quite incorrect. Oracle provides *two* downloads of Java 8 Update 311: (a) the regular product [*Oracle JDK*](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java8), and the cutting-edge new technology product, [*GraalVM Enterprise*](https://www.graalvm.org/downloads/).

Comment: @BasilBourque I guess it was correct back in 2015...

Answer (score 166):

Java8 is no longer available on homebrew, `brew install java8` will not work.

Instead, use:

```
brew cask install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8
```

See [this commit](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions/commit/2f7c1d5d1582a1fd465991fea8087b94cdbbd088) for technical details.

Please note as well you may see issues around `Cask adoptopenjdk8 exists in multiple taps`. This is a known issue, currently being worked on, which you can see here:

https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk/issues/106

For those who don't want to run through the details, here is a summary:

```
# To install JDK8
brew cask install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8

# To be able to safely run 'brew cleanup'
brew untap adoptopenjdk/openjdk
brew untap caskroom/versions
brew cleanup
```

Comment: Is there any difference in using `AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk` instead of using `homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8`

Comment: I get the following when I try your answer: Cask adoptopenjdk8 exists in multiple taps:
  caskroom/versions/adoptopenjdk8
  adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8

Comment: @KorayTugay I have updated the answer, this should solve your issues!

Comment: @SeanBreckenridge - the HomeBrew team are working on it, at the moment it looks like AdoptOpenJDK will be used, but there is still some uncertainty, see the currently open issue https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk/issues/106 for details!

Comment: `brew cask install homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8` worked for me

Comment: Once you have it installed and you want to set JAVA_HOME, where do you point it to?

Comment: @EvanZamir `export JAVA_HOME=\`/usr/libexec/java_home\``

Comment: `brew cask install adoptopenjdk8` doesn't need tapping.

Comment: this worked for me brew install --cask adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8

Comment: `brew install --cask adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8` worked for MacOS Monterey, 12.1. `cask` is no longer a brew command, see here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66286088/error-unknown-command-cask-despite-the-use-of-multiple-instance-trials

Answer (score 158):

## In 2023, you can use just `brew`

```
brew install openjdk@8
```

Apple silicon users should execute this first

```
env /usr/bin/arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh --login
```

and maybe you need to update `PATH` env:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk@8/bin:$PATH"
```

### …for the future give a try to [`sdkman`](https://sdkman.io/), is better than `brew`

```
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

then open a **new shell** and try `list` to see what you could install ;-)

```
sdk list java
```

At time of writing to install java 8 you could use:

```
sdk install java 8.0.322-tem
```

NOTE: Update the install command to match some existing Identifier show from running `sdk list java`

Comment: `$ jenv add /usr/local/opt/openjdk@11` => `ln: /Users/nakilon/.jenv/versions/openjdk64-11.0.9: No such file or directory`. Ah, ok, needed to run those commands that are going to bash_profile.

Comment: Have you run brew before jenv?

Comment: the brew method worked also had to update the path variables

Comment: you need to run export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk@8/bin:$PATH" after installing 

brew list  for install packages  

brew info $package_name for information of package

Comment: I think I messed up somewhere, after doing this, I got `Unrecognized option: --version
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`, while trying to do `java --version`

Comment: @pnv it’s a little weird. Maybe you have a mess with the PATH env, or many JDK installed in different ways. It’s hard to give you a hand from here.

Comment: as simple as that!

Comment: Had to do `brew install --build-from-source openjdk@8` to make it work

Comment: sdkman is a blessing

Comment: Sdk is the only answer worked for me. However, java 8.0.322-tem is no longer there. I have to use `sdk install java 8.0.352.fx-librca`

Comment: @YGao Thanks for sharing. At the time I wrote the post `8.0.322-tem` was available.

Comment: On M2 mac, : `Error: openjdk@8: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.` popped

Comment: @AayushShah thanks for letting me know. Now I still have an Intel... if you figure out please update the answer or write a comment here.

Comment: Just followed the three steps with sdkman and it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: openjdk@8: The x86_64 architecture is required for this software.

Comment: @ClaytonRabenda thanks for pointing out. I'll update the answer for Macos silicon users

Answer (score 130):

I just did this on my MBP, and had to use

```
$ brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
$ brew cask install java8
```

in order to get java8 to install.

Comment: How does that help?

Comment: It helped me with installing specific version of java. Now when java 9 is out, running "brew cask install java" installs java 9. "brew cask install java8" wasn't working for me until I ran "brew tap caskroom/versions".

Comment: Yes, `brew tap caskroom/versions` is required before installing java8

Comment: or just `brew install homebrew/cask-versions/java8` for the win!

Comment: It is not possible to install Java8 using Brew anymore because of Oracle license changes. Java8 is not available for public download anymore.

Comment: Oh no!  That must be very recent, because this workflow was working for me when I did it on my personal laptop just a couple weeks ago.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55775566/9306378 if you still want to use java8. Note that this uses OpenJDK though.

Comment: Looks like since Oracle's Java went license-only, my homebrew has started installing Open JDK for me by default.

Comment: `Error: Cask 'java8' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.`

Comment: @user924 how about this `brew cask install adoptopenjdk8` ?

Comment: This answer appears to be out of date by now; other answers give more up-to-date instructions.

Answer (score 88):

Assumption: Mac machine and you already have installed homebrew.

Install cask (with Homebrew 0.9.5 or higher, cask is included so skip this step):

```
$ brew tap caskroom/cask
$ brew tap caskroom/versions
```

To install latest java:

```
$ brew cask install java
```

To install java 8:

```
$ brew cask install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8
```

If you want to install/manage multiple version then you can use 'jenv':

Install and configure jenv:

```
$ brew install jenv
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ echo 'eval "$(jenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

Add the installed java to jenv:

```
$ jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home
$ jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.11.0_2.jdk/Contents/Home
```

To see all the installed java:

```
$ jenv versions
```

Above command will give the list of installed java:

```
* system (set by /Users/lyncean/.jenv/version)
1.8
1.8.0.202-ea
oracle64-1.8.0.202-ea
```

Configure the java version which you want to use:

```
$ jenv global oracle64-1.6.0.39
```

To set JAVA_HOME:

```
$ jenv enable-plugin export
```

Comment: Best solution! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you. Starts with short and to the point solution and continues with another useful tool: 'jenv' is handy to have around and is missing from most other answers. Helped with packaging Scala (2.12/2.13) code in 2020.

Comment: Works like a charm, brew cask install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8

Comment: This is the best answer indeed! Ideal for folks (like me) who have and need to manage multiple versions of java

Comment: 2022: Mac 12.x   :    
brew cask` is no longer a `brew` command. Use `brew <command> --cask` instead.
brew install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8 --cask

Answer (score 70):

An option that I am starting to really like for running applications on my local computer is to use Docker. You can simply run your application within the official JDK container - meaning that you don't have to worry about getting everything set up on your local machine (or worry about running multiple different versions of the JDK for different apps etc)

Although this might not help you with your current installation issues, it is a solution which means you can side-step the minefield of issues related with trying to get Java running correctly on your dev machine!

**The benefits are:**

1. No need to set up any version of Java on your local machine (you'll just run Java within a container which you pull from Docker Hub)
2. Very easy to switch to different versions of Java by simply changing the tag on the container.
3. Project dependencies are installed within the container - so if you mess up your config you can simply nuke the container and start again.

**A very simple example:**

Create a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM java:8
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
```

- Here we are specifying the Java container running version 8 of the SDK (`java:8` - to use Java 7, you could just specify: `java:7`)
- We are mapping the local directory with the directory: `/usr/src/myapp` inside the container

Create a `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "2"

services:
  java:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/myapp
```

Now, assume we have this Java file:

**HelloWorld.java**

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

So we have the following file structure:

```
.
|_ Dockerfile
|_ docker-compose.yml
|_ HelloWorld.java
```

You can do various Java things like:

**compile:**

```
docker-compose run --rm java javac HelloWorld.java
```

- You should note that the HelloWorld.class shows up in your current directory (this is cause we've mapped the current directory to the location inside the container where our code exists

**run:**

```
docker-compose run --rm java java HelloWorld
```

- Note: the first time you run this it will fetch the image etc. This will take a while - it only happens the first time
- `docker-compose run` - runs a command from within the container
- `-rm` tells docker to remove the container once the command is finished running
- `java` is the name of the service/container (from our docker-compose file) against which this command will run
- the rest of the line is the command to run inside the container.

This is quite a cool way of dealing with running different versions of Java for different apps without making a complete mess of your local setup :).

Here is a slightly more complex example which has [Maven and a simple Spring app](https://github.com/TangentSolutions/Spring-REST-Seed)

**Disclaimer:**

- I haven't really tried this within an IDE like IntelliJ - so not entirely sure how that aspect of things would work. [Though it looks like docker support is coming](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/03/docker-support-in-intellij-idea-14-1/)
- Here is a significantly more complex example running [Microservices with Spring Boot, Zuul and Docker](https://github.com/rohitghatol/spring-boot-microservices)

Comment: Good example using Docker, not sure why you got a downvote before.

Comment: I'd imagine the downvote because this does not answer the question of running Java on OS X/MacOS. Answering "How do I do this on platform X" with "Just use a VM/shim to do it on platform Y" is not productive.

Comment: especially for native java development (e.g. using SWIG, JNI and LIBRARY_PATH)

Answer (score 29):

## tl;dr

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` is the correct location for the JVM to be installed. This has been the case for several years now. Many years ago, other locations were used, but no longer.

You have a choice of several vendors to obtain an installer app to install a Java implementation on your Mac. Download an installer to run locally and then discard, as you commonly do for many apps.

Your Question mentions [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX)/OpenJFX. You might find it convenient to use a Java implementation that comes bundled with the OpenJFX libraries, such as [*LibericaFX*](https://bell-sw.com/pages/supported-configurations/) from BellSoft or [*ZuluFX*](https://www.azul.com/products/zulu-enterprise/zulufx-faq/) from Azul Systems.

## Use the Installer, Luke

Other answers suggesting the [*Homebrew*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) package manager seem a bit extreme to me. I am sure *Homebrew* has some good uses. But to simply run Java, or do Java programming, installing *Homebrew* is a needless extra step. Installing [*Homebrew* (package manager)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) for the single goal of obtaining Java is like building a [landing strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runway) to park your car instead of using your driveway. If you already have it, fine, use it. But suggesting *Homebrew* to those who simply need Java is poor advice.

People not already using Home-brew can simply download a Mac installer from a trusted source.

You have multiple sources to obtain an easy-to-use installer app to put Java on your Mac. Run the installer on your Mac just as you do for many other apps.

Here is a flowchart diagram for finding a source of Java 11, some of which also offer Java 8.

[image: Flowchart guiding you in choosing a vendor for a Java 11 implementation]

Download an installer from a vendor such as Adoptium(AdoptOpenJDK.net).

[image: Download page at AdoptOpenJDK.net]

Run the installer.

[image: screenshot of installer running]

## `JavaVirtualMachines` folder is now correct

> Why doesn't Oracle's installer put it where it really goes? And how can I work around this problem?

**Not a problem.**

The folder `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` is the new home for [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine)s on [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS).

[image: screenshot of the folder "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/" in the Finder]

To install a JVM, use an installer, discussed below.

To uninstall, simply use the Finder to delete a JVM from that folder. You will be prompted for system admin password to complete the removal.

---

## Java 9 & 10 & 11

Back in 2010, [Apple joined](https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/apple-joins-openjdk) the [*OpenJDK* project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK), along with [Oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Corporation), [IBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM), [Red Hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat), [Azul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azul_Systems), and other Java vendors. Each member contributes source code, testing, and feedback to the unified OpenJDK codebase.

Apple contributed most of its Mac-specific code for its JVM. Now Apple no longer releases its own Mac-specific JVM. You now have your choice of JVM supplier, with builds coming from the OpenJDK codebase.

You will find source code at: http://openjdk.java.net

## New release cadence

Be aware that in 2017, Oracle, the JCP, and OpenJDK have adopted a [new rapid “release train” plan](https://www.theserverside.com/news/450426185/Calling-all-aboard-on-the-six-month-Java-release-train) for regularly-scheduled versions of Java to be delivered in a predictable manner.

Read this 2018-07 Azul Systems blog post for many details, [*Eliminating Java Update Confusion by Simon Ritter*](https://www.azul.com/eliminating-java-update-confusion/).

Also read [*Java Is Still Free*](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-c02aef8c9e04).

### Vendors

For a rather exhaustive list of past and present JVM implementations, see [this page at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines).

Here is a discussion of a few vendors. See the flowchart above for more vendors

#### *Oracle JDK*

Oracle provides JDK and JRE installers for multiple platforms including macOS.

Over the years since acquiring Sun, Oracle has combined the best parts of the two JVM engines, [*HotSpot*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot) and [*JRocket*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JRockit), and merged them into the [*OpenJDK*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project used as the basis for their own branded implementations of Java.

Their new business plan, as of 2018, is to provide a Oracle-branded implementation of Java for a fee in production, and at no cost for use in development/testing/demo. Support for previous releases requires a paid support program. They have declared their intention for their branded release to be at feature-parity with the OpenJDK release. They have even donated their commercial add-ons such as *Flight Recorder* to the OpenJDK project.

Oracle also releases a build of OpenJDK with no support: http://jdk.java.net/

Oracle has produced a special purpose JDK, [GraalVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraalVM).

#### *Zulu* & *Zing* by Azul

[Azul Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azul_Systems) provides a variety of JVM products.

- Their `Zulu` line is based directly on OpenJDK, and is available at no cost with optional paid support plans.
- Their `Zing` line offers commercial JVM products enhanced with alternate technical implementations such as a specialized [garbage-collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)).

Both of their lines offer installers for macOS.

I am currently use *Zulu* for Java 10.0.1 on macOS [High Sierra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_High_Sierra) with [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) 2018.2 and [Vaadin 8](https://vaadin.com/framework). I [downloaded from this page](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/). By the way, I do *not* find any Java-related items installed on the Apple *System Preferences* app.

#### *Adoptium*

[Adoptium](https://adoptopenjdk.net), formerly known as *AdoptOpenJDK*, is a community-led effort to build binaries of the OpenJDK source. Many of the other vendors of Java implementations support this work at Adoptium.

- Your choice of either [*HotSpot*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot) or [*OpenJ9*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJ9) engine.
- Builds available for macOS, Linux, and Windows, and other platforms.

#### *OpenJ9* by Eclipse

The [*OpenJ9*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJ9) project is an another implementation of the JVM engine, an alternative to *HotSpot*.

Now sponsored at the Eclipse Foundation, with technology and backing donated by IBM in 2017.

For prebuilt binaries, they refer you to the *AdoptOpenJDK* project mentioned above.

[image: Motivations in choosing a vendor for Java]

---

## How to install

The installers provided by Oracle or by Azul are both utterly simple to operate. Just run the installer app on your Mac. A window appears to indicate the progress of the installation.

When completed, verify your JVM installation by:

- Visiting the `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` folder to see an item for the new JVM.
- Running a console such as *Terminal.app* and type `java -version` to see the brand and version number of your JVM.

After verifying success, dismount the .dmg image in the Finder. Then trash the .dmg file you downloaded.

Comment: This answer is odious.  Just use brew cask install adoptopenjdk8.

Comment: @user3562927 Installing [*Homebrew* (package manager)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) for the single goal of obtaining Java is like building a [landing strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runway) to park your car instead of just using your driveway. If you already have it, fine, use it. But suggesting *Homebrew* to those who simply need Java is poor advice. Apparently you are not the only easily-offended Homebrew fan, given the 5 down-votes left on this Answer without explanation. But I stand by my recommendation.

Comment: @BasilBourque brew is more useful than you think. It installs a lot of software so much easier, your answer is a proof for that :-/

Comment: @DanielW. The Question did not ask for a Brew solution, and did not even mention Brew. The Question asked about installing Java.  There are several important issues to consider in installing Java; those issues I tried to cover. Apparently I have offended some Brew fans — that was not my intention. My intention was to pointedly address the Question at hand, as is the practice on Stack Overflow. And I stand by my position: Installing Brew *just to install Java* is overkill. Furthermore, using Brew to install Java will limit choices and ignore issues when it comes to various Java implementations.

Answer (score 25):

I'm having the same problem to solve, because I need to install JDK8 to run Android SDK Manager (because it seems that don't work well with JDK9).
However, I tell you how I solve all problems on a Mac (Sierra).

First, you need **brew** with cask and **jenv**.

1. You can find an useful guide here,[Homebrew Cask Installation Guide](http://gillesfabio.github.io/homebrew-cask-homepage/).
   Remember to tap 'caskroom/versions' running in the terminal:
   `brew tap caskroom/versions`
2. After that, install jenv with:
   `brew install jenv`
3. Install whatever version you want with cask
   `brew cask install java8` (or `java7` or `java` if you want to install the latest version, jdk9)
4. The last step is to configure which version to run (and let jenv to manage your JAVA_HOME)
   `jenv versions` to list all versions installed on your machine and then activate the one you want with `jenv global [JDK_NAME_OF_LIST]`

You could find other useful informations here on this Github Gist [brew-java-and-jenv.md](https://gist.github.com/tomysmile/a9a7aee85ff73454bd57e198ad90e614), on this blog [Install multiple JDK on a Mac](http://davidcai.github.io/blog/posts/install-multiple-jdk-on-mac/) and on [Jenv Website](http://www.jenv.be/)

Comment: jenv is quite easy and super useful. I have multiple projects that need java 8 and 11

Answer (score 23):

If you have several Java versions on your machine and you want to choose it dynamically at runtime, i.e, in my case, I have two versions:

```
ls -la /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel    96B Nov 16  2014 jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel    96B Mar  1  2015 jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/
```

You can change them by modifying the `/etc/profile` content. Just add (or modify) the following two lines at the end of the file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=YOUR_JAVA_PATH/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

In my case, it should be like the following if I want to use:

Java 7:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Java 8:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

After saving the file, **please run** `source /etc/profile` and it should work. Here are results when I use the first and second option accordingly:

Java 7:

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
```

Java 8:

```
java -version 
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
```

The process is similar if your java folder is located in different locations.

Comment: Why not making an alias for different version, like `alias java8=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`?

Answer (score 23):

Please, run the following commands and it will install Java 8 on OS X:

```sh
brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk
brew install --cask homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8
```

Note:

adoptopenjdk8 has been officially discontinued upstream.
It may stop working correctly (or at all) in recent versions of macOS. So, this is working at the moment, but, please, don't use this answer to install Java 8

Comment: Glad that helped you :)

Comment: should be the only accepted solution, works like charm.

Answer (score 22):

It seems that nobody has mentioned SDK man (https://sdkman.io/) yet.

SKD man allows installing multiple versions of Java on Mac and easy switching between these versions. More information is available at https://sdkman.io/usage.

For example:

````
$ sdk list java                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
================================================================================
Available Java Versions
================================================================================
   * 12.ea.20-open
     11.0.1-zulu
 > * 11.0.1-open
     10.0.2-zulu
     10.0.2-open
     9.0.7-zulu
     9.0.4-open
     8.0.192-zulu
     8.0.191-oracle
   + 8.0.181-oracle
     7.0.181-zulu
     1.0.0-rc-10-grl
     1.0.0-rc-9-grl
     1.0.0-rc-8-grl


================================================================================
+ - local version
* - installed
> - currently in use
================================================================================

$ sdk install java 8.0.191-oracle

$ sdk use java 8.0.191-oracle

Using java version 8.0.191-oracle in this shell.                                                                                                                                                                                                      

$ java -version                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)

$ sdk use java 11.0.1-open                                           

Using java version 11.0.1-open in this shell.

$ java -version                                                                                                                                                                                                                        openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)
                                                                                                                                                                                                         ```
````

Comment: I'm getting this pop-up : 
----------------------------
Stop! java 8.0.191-oracle is not available. Possible causes:
 * 8.0.191-oracle is an invalid version
 * java binaries are incompatible with your platform
 * java has not been released yet
----------------------------

Comment: Indeed 8.0.191-oracle is not among the list anymore. You can use `sdk list java` to check other distributions

Answer (score 19):

```
brew cask install caskroom/versions/java8
```

Answer (score 17):

for 2021 (also 2022 and 2023) this one worked for me

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions


brew install --cask adoptopenjdk8
```

Comment: This worked in 2022 , after installation the following commands can be used to validate your installation `java` , `java -version` . The commands `java --version` and `which java` do not give proper results though.

Comment: Small update to this. `brew` suggests to use `brew install --cask temurin8` instead. (I did not realize Temurin made also Java 8 version)

Answer (score 16):

I have applications that use both Java 7 and 8 and have to go back and forth all the time.

I use this script written by Johan:

http://www.jayway.com/2014/01/15/how-to-switch-jdk-version-on-mac-os-x-maverick/

You can now set it at startup or call the script afterwards.
Install the JDK for Mac.

**Java 7**

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

**Java 8**

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

---

**Updated recommendation!!**:

Use jenv https://www.jenv.be/ and homebrew.

Then its just `jenv global oracle6401.6.0.39` and its set.

Comment: +1: i use this script and i agree, it's pretty useful for devs who have multiple projects that require different versions of Java.

Comment: There is really no need to set any scripts as long as you only need to use a specific version system-wide. Basically all you need to do is add to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`: *export JAVA_HOME="/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8"* and also add your `$JAVA_HOME/bin` to `$PATH` if the java installer didn't do it already. (NOTE: replace double quotes with backticks for /usr/libexec/java_home, can't enter literal backticks in comments..)

Comment: if you want to install java 7 (along side java 8) via homebrew, the command is `brew tap caskroom/versions` followed by `brew cask install java7`.

Comment: [jenv](https://github.com/gcuisinier/jenv) is a very convenient tool for managing multiple versions of Java, either globally or locally per-directory.

Answer (score 11):

Run these commands on mac **High Sierra**

```
brew update
brew tap caskroom/versions
brew cask install java8
```

and check with command

```
java -version
```

Comment: Getting this: ```Error: Download failed on Cask 'java8' with message: Download failed: https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u202-b08/1961070e4c9b4e26a04e7f5a083f551e/jdk-8u202-macosx-x64.dmg```

Answer (score 11):

As of Year - 2021

```
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8
```

Comment: This is the one that worked for me today.

Answer (score 8):

If you are on a Mac, then Homebrew is the way to install stuff.

It seems that version 8 is no longer the most recent, so it isnt available using the default `brew cask install java`.

Instead I managed by doing the following:

```
brew install homebrew/cask-versions/
```

If this fails, just try the next one directly:

```
brew install homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8
```

Test with `brew cask list` or `java -version`

Comment: +1, that works for me on macOS 10.12.6 Sierra. (Or brew cask install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8)

Comment: +1 The first one failed (Error: No available formula with the name "homebrew/cask-versions/" ), but the second one seemed to work. Updated answer to avoid scaring people off with the first faillure.

Answer (score 8):

brew cask commands were disabled on **2020-12-21 with the release of Homebrew 2.7.0.**

Use the below commands to install JDK

**brew install --cask adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8**

Answer (score 7):

Using brew

```
brew install Caskroom/cask/java
```

Answer (score 7):

Best way is to use Brew package manager but the command

```
 brew cask install java8
```

fails with error:

```html
Error: No available formula with the name "java8"
```

So use

```html
brew cask install caskroom/versions/java8
```

How did I find "caskroom/versions/java8": using brew search command:

```
brew cask search java8
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using it **NOT** for personal use, you might want to use OpenJDK instead to avoid any potential lawsuit from Oracle.

```
brew cask install adoptopenjdk8
```

Comment: find /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/ | grep -i jdk | xargs rm -v
if you happen the get the "Error: Cask adoptopenjdk8 exists in multiple taps:" error ...

Answer (score 7):

You can try this:

```
$ brew search jdk
$ brew install --cask homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8
$ /usr/libexec/java_home
```

Answer (score 5):

**Install with Homebrew**

The version of Java available in Homebrew Cask previous to October 3, 2018 was indeed the Oracle JVM. Now however, it has now been updated to OpenJDK. Be sure to update Homebrew and then you will see the lastest version available for install.

**1. install Homebrew if you haven't already. Make sure it is updated:**

```
brew update
```

**2. Add the casks tap, if you haven't already (or you are not seeing older Java versions anymore with step #3):**

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
```

**3. and for the AdoptOpenJDK versions, add that tap:**

```
brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk
```

These casks change their Java versions often, and there might be other taps out there with additional Java versions.

**4. Look for installable versions:**

```
brew search java
```

or for AdoptOpenJDK versions:

```
brew search jdk
```

**5. Check the details on the version that will be installed:**

```
brew cask info java
```

or for the AdoptOpenJDK version:

```
brew cask info adoptopenjdk
```

**6. Install a specific version of the JDK such as java11, adoptopenjdk8, or just java or adoptopenjdk for the current. For example:**

```
**brew cask install java**

**brew cask install java8**

**brew cask install java11**
```

**You can use the fully qualified path to older versions as well:**

```
brew cask install homebrew/cask-versions/java11
```

Comment: Presumably I did something wrong, but when trying to do java8 I got an error: Error: Cask 'java8' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.

Answer (score 5):

`brew search openjdk`
find some openjdk formulae, in 2021, brew offer openjdk11 and openjdk8 as options.

Comment: what should be next command after searching?

Answer (score 5):

MacOS Big Sur **2021 Java 8** installation guide:

1. Go to https://profile.oracle.com/myprofile/account/create-account.jspx and sign up if not already;
2. Go to https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk17-mac
3. Select "Java 8";
4. Select "macOS";
5. Press on "jdk-8u301-macosx-x64.dmg";
   [image: Java 8 download page]
6. Check the checkbox;
7. Press "Download jdk-8u301-macosx-x64.dmg";
8. Open the downloaded file;
9. Follow installation guide;

Enjoy =)

Comment: In order to test if the installation was successful run the following command on terminal  'javac -version'

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir Kuzomenskyi, I have installed successfully with help of your simple steps.

Answer (score 5):

***Eclipse Temurin*** is the official successor to adoptopenjdk.
So, as of May 2022, I would use the following

```
brew install --cask temurin8
```

When the installation is done, JDK 8 is installed in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-8.jdk`

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way

```
1) brew cask install java

2) java -version

java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
```

P.S - Cask is an extension to Homebrew that is intended to manage large Mac binaries and graphical applications, but using the Homebrew interface. Also see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/125471/13181) on Apple StackExchange.

Comment: it always installs the latest version

Answer (score 4):

Simplest is to download the dmg file from following site and install by double click

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
```

look for available JVMs from home directory

```
ls -al /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
```

and update the .bash_profile with relevent version

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_XXX.jdk./Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

and finally

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 3):

As of `2023`, `brew install --cask zulu8` didn't work for me on `Apple` chip. `brew install openjdk@8` also didn't not. The only one solution worked for me was `brew install --cask adoptopenjdk8` and then of course `vim ~/.zshrc` with `export JAVAC_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/` inside that file.

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
brew cask install java 8
```

it will give the below result

```
8tracksradiohelper       adoptopenjdk8            amitv87-pip              
corretto8                icons8                   vmware-fusion8           
x48                      zulu8
```

Next enter:

```
brew cask install adoptopenjdk8
```

---- java 8 will be installed in Mac.

Comment: `brew cask install java 8` gave me a completely different list: `eclipse-java`, `netbeans-java-ee`, `oracle-jdk-javadoc`, `eclipse-javascript`, `netbeans-java-se`

Comment: This no longer works.
I have `Homebrew 2.7.1` running on Mac OS Catalina 10.15.4

Using `brew tap` followed by `brew install --cask` from another comment apparently worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Update HomeBrew from here - [How to install Java 8 on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342886/how-to-install-java-8-on-mac)

And then install Zulu M1 JDK from here.
https://cdn.azul.com/zulu/bin/zulu8.66.0.15-ca-jdk8.0.352-macosx_aarch64.dmg

Post download Set JDK Home in your path like below:

```
export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home'
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is the Zulu java prebuilts. They even come with an installer that does all the work for you.

https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-8-lts&os=macos&package=jdk

Answer (score -4):

Below steps worked for me.

1) Uninstall all jdks

In the Terminal window Copy and Paste the command below:

```
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin

sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefpane
```

2) Install APPLE jdk.

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US

3) Download latest JDK from Oracle and install it , for me it was JDK 1.82

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

Thats all it will work like a charm.