# why I can not open my Android Device Monitor on Mac?

Tags: android-studio, android-device-monitor

I read the solution from 
[Mac - I cann't open my Android Device Monitor on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057720/mac-i-cant-open-android-device-monitor-on-mac)
and followed the steps also.
But still now I am getting this kind of pop up window.

[image]

Is there any one who knows the possible solution of this problem?

Comment: No one did not give any suggestion or answer or anything that this is an duplicate question or something.So why you guys are giving downvote ??? At first show my faults and than downvote I wouldn't say anything.