# Update to Latest JDK on MacBook Pro El Capitan

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-deployment-toolkit

I have a MacBook Pro and I am trying to update to the latest JDK (1.8) so that I can run Android Studio. I currently run 1.7 but need it updated to the latest, 1.8. I have all of my OSX software up to date, so I am a bit confused as to why I don't automatically have the latest JDK. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install java 8 on Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342886/how-to-install-java-8-on-mac)