# Failed to initialize compiler: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found

Tags: scala, ubuntu

On Ubuntu 16.04, I installed `scala`:

```
$ls ~/Binary/scala-2.11.8
bin  doc  lib  man
$grep -A 2 SCALA ~/.bashrc
SCALA=~/Binary/scala-2.11.8
SBT=~/Binary/sbt
export PATH=$PATH:$SCALA/bin:$SBT/bin
```

With `openjdk8` installed, `scala` fails when opening the REPL:

```
$javac -version
javac 1.8.0_91
$ 
$scala
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 9-internal).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.
scala> 
Failed to initialize compiler: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
** Note that as of 2.8 scala does not assume use of the java classpath.
** For the old behavior pass -usejavacp to scala, or if using a Settings
** object programmatically, settings.usejavacp.value = true.

Failed to initialize compiler: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
** Note that as of 2.8 scala does not assume use of the java classpath.
** For the old behavior pass -usejavacp to scala, or if using a Settings
** object programmatically, settings.usejavacp.value = true.
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: What is the value of JAVA_HOME in your machine?

Comment: It's not set. But, I fixed it by `sudo update-alternatives --config javac` to use openjdk-8 rather than `/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`.

Comment: Did setting the JAVA_HOME erase the error?

Comment: On my machine setting the JAVA_HOME erased the error

Comment: I had the same problem, and changing the java version to 8 made the trick.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Using the Java 8 version of OpenJDK resolved this issue for me.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Comment: installing specific java version on osx with brew: https://www.lonecpluspluscoder.com/2017/10/08/installing-other-versions-of-the-java-jdk-via-homebrew/

Comment: Very Helpful answer!

Comment: This is a linux question, but if you are having this issue on a Mac, follow these instructions to install Java8 in your system (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342886/how-to-install-java-8-on-mac), and set your new JAVA_HOME accordingly (see @Dbz answer below).

Comment: I was using Java 10, and downgrading to version 8 of OpenJDK indeed worked! However, I also had to update the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the proper folder for it to work, in case anyone needs to do this as well.

Comment: Using the Java 8 version worked for me on Ubuntu without any further change. Great answer

Comment: As mentioned, downgrade to legacy software is an bad option. This is not an correct answer. Only option is to update scala and sbt

Answer (score 15):

Java 8 is deprecated, so downgrading to is must NOT be an acceptable solution.

The correct solution is to upgrade your SBT to 0.13.17 or higher.

Comment: The only correct answer out of 8 others, and zero upvotes!

Answer (score 10):

This issue appears to be with Java 9 and gets solved with Java 8.

If you have Java 8 and Java 9, and you would like to keep both, you can set your environment variable `JAVA_HOME` to the Java 8 path.

For example:

`export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home`

You will need to replace `jdk1.8.0_161.jdk` with whichever version of the JDK that you have.

You can find that version with:

`ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`

Once you set that environment variable, you can open a new terminal and run `java -version` to see if the version was set correctly.

EDIT:

It may be worth noting that I have a Mac even though this is a linux question.

Answer (score 6):

Installing java version "1.8.0_144" resolved the issue for me. I had installed jdk 1.9 previously.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using an older version of Scala that is not compatible with JDK greater than 8, [update to a newer version that's compatible with JDK 11](https://github.com/sbt/zinc/issues/641#issuecomment-588590196).  JDK 11 is current the LTS.

Versions by minor version:

- For 2.11.x this means `2.11.12` or [later](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/all.html)
- For 2.12.x this means `2.12.10` or [later](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/all.html)
- For 2.13.x this means `2.13.1` or [later](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/all.html)

As other answers mentioned, make sure you're also using a build tool that's compatible with JDK >8 (e.g. sbt greater than `0.13.17`).

Answer (score 2):

Installing Java 8 resolved this issue.

I downloaded java 8 and i extracted that to the following location : /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_172

After doing this update the JAVA_HOME path to the same : /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_172

This will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Worked with this java version "1.8.0_144"

Uninstall java and apache-spark

install java, install apache-spark

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same issue. Uninstall Java 9

```
sudo rm -fr /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
```

Ref: https://gist.github.com/schnell18/bcb9833f725be22f6acd01f94b486392

Install Java 8.

Everything seems to good now.

Btw: this was for mac. Might be useful for you.

Answer (score -2):

i had a zip of my jdk at the same location. Removing the zip did the trick for me.