# Scala compiler other than 2.12 not working in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala

I just set up a Scala project in Eclipse (Oxygen 4.7.3a, on Ubuntu 18.04) with the Scala-IDE plugin (4.7.0.v-2_12-201709291352-71a28d0) with a simple HelloWorld object. If I set "Properties -> Scala Compiler" to 2.12 everything works as expected: the project compiles and runs. But if I choose any other version (for instance, "Latest 2.10 bundle (dynamic)" I get prompted to do a full rebuild (as expected) but when I go to "Project -> Build" nothing happens. If I have errors in my code, the editor underlines them, but they won't show in "Problems". If I try to run it I get a class not found error.

I get the feeling that it is not actually compiling. Any ideas on what I need to configure differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by removing openjdk-11 and installing openjdk-8. After doing that and reinstalling Eclipse and Scala-IDE everything works fine.

It would have been helpful having some feedback from Eclipse regarding what was not working. I figured it out because I tried to build with SBT and the error lead to this SO question: [Failed to initialize compiler: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602889/failed-to-initialize-compiler-object-java-lang-object-in-compiler-mirror-not-fo)

I tried the update-alternatives option (also changing the Java path in eclipse.ini) but then I got the "object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found" error in Eclipse problems. Since I didn't need openjdk-11 anyway I simply switched to openjdk-8.