# Why I cannot use spark interpreter in zeppelin?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

In the picture, it turned out that I can use python interpreter but not spark. I have no idea why. Please give me help. I'm totally lost.
[Here is the command window of zeppelin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiLfM.png)
My code is just 1 + 1 , to test whether I can run different interpreter.

[here is the bash window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYfqq.png)

Comment: oh sorry, I'll delete it and reask.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'm a newbie in programming world☺️

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you have incompatible versions of Java and Scala or JAVA_HOME is not set.

Please go thru this related question, how to fix and about the issue

[Failed to initialize compiler: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602889/failed-to-initialize-compiler-object-java-lang-object-in-compiler-mirror-not-fo)

Comment: How to change Java version

Comment: Thank you so much! I download the needed JDK 8 from the oracle and remove the previous version in my mac. And now I can run the scala code in zeppelin.