# scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found. PredictionIO SETUP

Tags: java, scala, predictionio

I'm trying to setup a predictionIO engine for further use in my project, I'm facing this issue while building the app in prediction for a recommendation engine

```
`[INFO] [Engine$] [error] (Compile / compileIncremental) scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.`
```

**Java Version**

`openjdk version "1.8.0_252"`

`OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-8u252-b09-1~16.04-b09) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)`

**Scala Version**

`2.11.12`

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I see someone had similar issue in the past and one of answers was upgrading sbt https://stackoverflow.com/a/60118115/4099089 I would try it.

Comment: No I'm not able to solve it. I'm creating a predictionIO recommendation engine and While building the app it crashes and throws the above error. Do you have any idea how to upgrade sbt version in the predictionIO setup?

Answer (score 0):

It has taken me days to fix it.

If you encount the error "scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found."

For short, it is probably caused by the compatibility of your scala code(or dependency) and JVM. Trying to downgrade to SDK 1.8, set and export JAVA_HOME again,  then remove all repositories under ~/.m2/repository may evict this problem.