# R is not detecting the latest Java version (1.8) installed when using sparklyr package

Tags: r, sparklyr

R is not detecting the latest Java version (1.8) installed for the usage of sparklyr package.

```
config <- spark_config()
config$sparklyr.gateway.port = 10000
config$sparklyr.gateway.connect.timeout = 1  
config$sparklyr.gateway.start.wait = 1000
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr) 
library(DBI)
sc <- spark_connect(master="yarn-client", method = c("shell"),config=config, app_name = "sparklyr",version="2.0.0", extensions = sparklyr::registered_extensions())

Error in validate_java_version(spark_home) : 
Java version1.6.0.65 detected but 1.7+ is required. Please download and 
install Java from https://www.java.com/en/
```

I updated the Java version and confirmed in Mac terminal. Then I restarted the Rsession:

```
/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java -
version 
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

But I'm still getting the same error outdated Java version:

```
Error in validate_java_version(spark_home) : 
Java version1.6.0.65 detected but 1.7+ is required. Please download and 
install Java from https://www.java.com/en/
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Currently (beginning 2019, version 0.9.4) `sparklyr` requires java v1.7-1.8 and the default version installed on macOSX is usually 1.6.

You can check your version in the terminal with

```
java -version
```

If you get something like

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-468-11M4833)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-468, mixed mode)
```

you need to update it. If you have `brew` installed, simply do:

```
brew tap caskroom/versions
brew cask install java8
```

Once you do that you can check the installation on your local machine with

```
ls -1 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
```

Usually, after restarting the R session, `sparklyr` should recognise the right version (1.8). 
If that would *NOT* be the case, you can set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable in `R` with:

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME = "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk/Contents/Home")
```

This works for me when using the [RStudio recommended guidelines for connecting](https://spark.rstudio.com/guides/connections/) in `local` mode.

**I have another java version, what do I do?**

It's important to type `java8` when calling the `brew cask install` otherwise the latest version of java would be installed. I did this mistake and installed `openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15`.

If you have a similar situation do `brew cask remove java` to uninstall java and get the right version required.

This info is comes from an [issue on the sparklyr GitHub Repo](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/1383) and another [stackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342886/how-to-install-java-8-on-mac).

Comment: The brew command needs to be updated because of recent changes to Oracle's licensing requirements. I'd recommend `$ brew cask install homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8`. Then, from R: `Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME = "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home")`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by installing the latest JAVA version from the following website:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

You could further check if the version was updated successfully by running the following command on mac terminal:

```
java -version
```

Now I'm able to use the sparklyr package.