# Unable to run react native project due to java version 10

Tags: react-native

I have got the react native installation done but with latest jdk version that is v10.
Now when I try to run the project using the command **react-native run-android**, I am getting the following error,

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '10'.
```

I'm pretty much new to the MAC environment, How do I roll back to the previous working version of java in Mac?
How I can fix this issue?

Comment: This generally means that the Java might have been deleted successfully, but its environment path still remains, either you may follow the steps in the post [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342886/how-to-install-java-8-on-mac/28635465) here or try changing your `java env variable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade the Java version.
This is a problem with the latest version of java.

Comment: IMHO: To call this a "problem with the latest version of Java" is a bit of a stretch when the core problem lies in the fact that RN _still_ creates a Android-wrapper-project like it was 2013 (when Android API 23 was released).

Answer (score 14):

You need a change in the Android

Gradle properties file.

> PROJECT_PATH/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

Update your distributionUrl to the following

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.3-rc-2-all.zip
```