# Unrecognized VM option 'ExitOnOutOfMemoryError' when starting Presto

Tags: presto

I was following the [installation manual for presto](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/deployment.html).

But when I lanched the presto server from the command line I got this error:

```
$ bin/launcher run

Unrecognized VM option 'ExitOnOutOfMemoryError'
Did you mean 'OnOutOfMemoryError=<value>'?
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 2):

Per [@kavehmb's answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32811065/124355), as of June 2019 the way to work around this issue is:

```
brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk
brew cask install adoptopenjdk8
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspected the java version was wrong and checked it. I had Java 1.8.0_65-b17.

The documentation for the installation did not mention anything about needed java version. It was hard to find out the needed Java version for the newest Presto version (v0.208)

I updated to the currently newest Java8 version using brew (on Mac).

```
brew cask install java8
```

After successful upgrading of Java I had version 1.8.0_181-b13.

Then prestodb could start.