# Can't install Eclipse - "Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine" on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to install Eclipse, but I can't get the installer to start. It fails with

> "Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine"

How can I resolve this?

Note: I'm on Mac.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Edit the file /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Info.plist

There is a comment for use a particular JVM:

```xml
<key>Eclipse</key>
<array>
    <!-- to use a specific Java version (instead of the platform's default) uncomment one of the following options,
        or add a VM found via $/usr/libexec/java_home -V -->
    <string>-vm</string><string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk8u192-b12/Contents/Home/jre/</string>
    <string>-keyring</string>
    <string>~/.eclipse_keyring</string>
</array>
```

Comment: can you pls explain this in detail, i opened the file and now I'm blacked out about what to do next.

Comment: It is already explained. Please, take a look on the xml comment above.

Answer (score 26):

It took me some time to figure this out as well. The main takeaway was **eclipse does not support SDK Version 14** (as of eclipse 2020-03). That was not completely obvious to me.

1. Install a supported version (I used Homebrew to install SDK V8 ):

   ```
    brew cask install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8
   ```

   If this is the only Java Version you have installed you should be fine and Eclipse should open up. If that is not the case and you have another Java Version installed. You have to tell Eclipse which Version of Java it should be using (see Step 2).
2. Tell Eclipse which Version to use by editing the `/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Info.plist` file as described by [Juan Ignacio Barisich](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56532418/4179020) and [Brad Parks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52652847/4179020). **That being the version you installed in step 1**.

   ```
    nano /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Info.plist
    # or
    open /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Info.plist
   ```

   ```xml
    <key>Eclipse</key>
    <array>
        <string>-keyring</string>
        <string>~/.eclipse_keyring</string>
        <string>-vm</string>
        <string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/</string>
    </array>
   ```

**Disclaimer:** Please bare in mind that those were the steps I took to get eclipse running again. Because I'm nowhere qualified to give a precise answer about this please take a look at the comments in case I got something wrong.

**Edit:** See [Christian Fries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60970143/4179020) answer who pointed out that all java versions 8 to 13 are supported by eclipse.

Comment: No this is not true. On macOs Eclipse does not run with Oracle Java 14.0.0 due a bug of Java, but **fine with 14.0.1**. See [here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60771575/6505250). Please note that the question was asked even before Java 14 was released.

Comment: Changing to use OpenJDK 17 fixed the problem for me (as I didn't want to keep using an old version of Java).

Answer (score 15):

For me, I had to edit the `eclipse-inst.ini` file located here:

```
Eclipse Installer.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse-inst.ini
```

and add the path to my local java VM **at the very top of the .ini file**, which is here:

```
-vm
/Users/bparks/jdk/jdk1.8.0_162_x64/bin/java
```

If the `Eclipse Installer.app` file is in a DMG, right click on it, and copy it, then paste it into another folder. Then right click on that app file, and choose "Show Package Contents", to get into the files inside the application.

If you've already got Eclipse installed, and find it's throwing the same error, you could try a similar approach by editing the following file for Eclipse:

```
/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini
```

On mac, you can get the full path you'd need to your java exe by running the following in a terminal, which will copy the path to your clipboard.

```
$ echo $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/bin/java | pbcopy
```

Comment: I know this is an old post, but how do I edit the eclipse-inst.ini file? I have tried using sudo vi but I get 'permission denied' or 'read only file'. The downloaded file is a .dmg

Comment: Been too long - but my guess is that I copied all the files out of the DMG, and put them in a folder somewhere on my mac, then edited that!

Comment: I've revised the answer to include how I think I did it

Comment: Hi, where in `eclipse-inst.ini` should I add the path? I added it in the file and when I try and run the DMG, macos says it's damaged and should be trashed.

Comment: @user1753491 - The file you're editing shouldn't be in the DMG anymore, it's in the app - so just run the `Eclipse Installer.app` you copied out of the DMG and edited, and see if that works

Comment: @BradParks Another stuck person joining the comment thread; I was able to edit the file and paste in my JVM path, but it still says that no JVM is able to be created.

Comment: I'm not using Eclipse these days, so I don't know sadly - the above worked for me, from what I recall!

Comment: @fin444 uninstall JDK 14 and install JDK 8 through homebrew. That solved my issue.

Comment: @user1753491 Thanks for the help! I uninstalled all JDK versions other than 8 and it worked.

Comment: @user1753491 Probably because you had Java 14.0.0, which has a bug that prevents Eclipse from starting on macOS, which has been fixed in Java 14.0.1. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60771575/6505250

Comment: @fin444 Probably because you had Java 14.0.0, which has a bug that prevents Eclipse from starting on macOS, which has been fixed in Java 14.0.1. See stackoverflow.com/a/60771575/6505250

Comment: vote you up .. for me below works: 
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

Answer (score 11):

**Note**: The error "**Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine**" also exists with **Eclipse 2020-03** (under some situations, see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=561273) and it is not required to use Java 8 (with Eclipse 2020-03).

**For the impatient:**

You can run Eclipse or the Eclipse Installer with a given VM without changing `eclipse.ini` by starting it via a command line:

- Open Terminal an run:
- `open PATHTOECLIPSEINSTALLER/Eclipse\ Installer.app --args -vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/NAMEOFJDK/Contents/Home/bin`

where `PATHTOECLIPSEINSTALLER` is the path of the folder where Eclipse Installer is located and `NAMEOFJDK` is the name of the folder with the JDK (11, 12, 13).

For example:

`open Downloads/Eclipse\ Installer.app --args -vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin`

In the installer you may select the VM used by Eclipse. Use a compatible VM here and the installer will modify the `eclipse.ini` for you.

**Explanation TL;DR**

To clarify this issue:

Eclipse - say Eclipse 2020-03 - runs with Java 11, Java 12, Java 13, but does not run with Java 14. It fails with the message "Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine". This happens for the installer and for Eclipse itself.

You can download Eclipse without the installer from here: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/

**Explanation:**

On macOS, if you start a freshly installed Eclipse, it will use the default JVM. The default JVM is obtained by running `/usr/libexec/java_home`.

This program `/usr/libexec/java_home` will find the installed JDK with the highest version as default. That is, if you have JDK 14 installed and run Eclipse 2020-03, you will see this error.

**Solution**

Summarising some other answers here, there are three options:

1. Once you have removed JDK 14 from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ the error will be gone.
2. If you like to have JDK 14 installed, start the installer with a different JDK via the command line `open Path-to-Eclipse-Installer/Eclipse\ Installer.app --args -vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/NAMEOFJDK/Contents/Home/bin`
3. You may edit the eclipse.ini (as suggested in other answers) to use a specific JVM.

Comment: This solution solved my issue, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I started facing the same problem in mac suddenly after updating to ***macOS Monterey***, So I just did the following steps:
[image]
Then go to ***Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini***  file and open it with any text editor and you will see the following:
[image]
Add below line before -vmargs as shown in above image:

```
-vm  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

This below line will be different for all the users:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

and you can just get this line copied to your clipboard using this command in terminal:

```
$ echo $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/bin/java | pbcopy
```

****Similarly will be for STS:****

[image]
Then go to ***`Contents/Eclipse/SpringToolSuite4.ini`*** as shown below and open with any text editor app.
[image]

You will see the following:
[image]
Just add the same line that you added for Eclipse in the above steps:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Referring to Marseille Joseph 
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1102885&goto=1823113&#msg_num_13
This worked for me!

Their solution didn't require uninstalling jdk14 or to editing the eclipse.ini file. Instead, do this:

```sh
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/MacOS/
sudo rm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/libjli.dylib libjli.dylib
```

Answer (score 1):

delete all java folder inside /Library/Java

then install a new jdk from 
https://adoptopenjdk.net/

which will install at
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk

then try reinstalling eclipse a

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in my mac. Here is my solution.

First: I've uninstall all the versions of jdk, because I've try a lot of options.
To do this, you need to go to Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
and delete all the folders.

Second: Install jdk 1.8 here is a link to download this version:
[jdk 1.8](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html)

Third: Install [eclipse 2020-03](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/2020-03/R/eclipse-inst-mac64.dmg) and thats all.

If you want to use JDK 14, you need to follow this steps:

1. Open eclipse
2. Go to Help > Install new software
3. In the Install window copy the following link in **Work with** https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.15-P-builds/

[image: Install window]

4. Select the third option show in the picture below
   [image: Option]
5. Then, click "next" and finish the install

Now you have to change the options, go to Preferences (command + ,) > Java > Compiler and search the version 14. *Before this step you need to install jdk 14 ([link](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk14-downloads.html))* Perhaps eclipse would suggest you to change to the correct JREs, for this you need to go to Java > Installed JREs and add the correct version. When you click **add** you need to choose he JRE type, in my case I use a MacOS X VM and Standard VM, then you have to choose the directory (/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachine/jdk-14/Contents/Home and click **open** you could give a JRE Name and **finish** eclipse will be restart and now you can use eclipse with java 14.

[image]

This works for me, I hope you have understood me.

Answer (score 1):

Go to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines

Delete all version except one in use.

Answer (score 1):

Install jdk 8 from brew work for me. You can get the instruction on installing Jdk 8 from HomeBrew here [How to install Java 8 on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342886/how-to-install-java-8-on-mac)

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem with `eclipse-java-2020-03-M2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64`, and **opendjdk11**. The latest eclipse installer at the moment also complained same error.

After I switched back to **openjdk8**, everything goes well...

Comment: similar issue found: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/6353 https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1102062/

Answer (score 0):

For Windows OS:

1. open eclipse.ini in the Eclipse program folder
2. add the below lines at the top of the file

*-vm*

path-to-java-bin\javaw.exe (for example: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10\bin\javaw.exe)

Answer (score 0):

I mounted eclipse dmg file and copied eclipse inside Applications. Then I tried to modify file Info.plist located inside Contents as below, but was getting that this file Info.plist is readonly error. I noticed that I already have read and write permission but still it was giving me that read only error. Then I moved the contents of Eclipse to some other local folder and then edited Info.plist, it did not give me readonly error.

```
<array>             
  <string>-vm</string><string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>         
  <string>-keyring</string>
  <string>~/.eclipse_keyring</string>           
</array>
```

Finally I am able to open eclipse.