# Eclipse provides "Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine"

Tags: java, eclipse

Platform: MAC Catalina 10.15.3 (64 bit)
Eclipse: eclipse-java-2020-03-R-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.dmg (64 bit)

This was as a result of attempting to fix and issue where the eclipse JRE was `The container 'JRE System Library [...]' references non existing library '...'` and the subsequent fix. After these modifications were made I shut down eclipse and on restarting it I encountered this error. Importantly, doing `echo $JAVA_HOME` provides nothing in return. The below journals the other attempts to get Eclipse up and running.

After uninstalling and reinstalling both eclipse and java I still get the error "Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine".

On running `./eclipse` from the command line I get:

```
Error: could not find libjava.dylib
Failed to GetJREPath()
```

On running `./eclipse -vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home/lib` from the command line I get:

```
cmacedo@Christians-MBP eclipse % ./eclipse -vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home/lib
Error: could not find libjava.dylib
Failed to GetJREPath()
```

On checking the folder `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home/lib` I see it does indeed contain `libjava.dylib`

And, if I attempt to do the below, I get a `permissions denied`:

```
cmacedo@Christians-MBP ~ % echo "export JAVA_HOME=`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home/`" >> ~/.profile
zsh: permission denied: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

Comment: .../Contents/Home is the usual location to specify (no lib at the end)

Comment: @greg-449 that starts it up from the command line. And idea what I need to modify so eclipse uses this each time?

Comment: It may help if you [edit] your question and add a couple of [probably unimportant] details. Namely what Eclipse version are you using and what platform are you on, e.g. Windows or linux or Mac. Also is that 32-bit or 64-bit platform?

Comment: Doing a quick test here I get this error using the latest Eclipse 2020-03 (but without the Java 14 patch). Not sure if the patch helps.

Comment: @greg-449 Which of the three are you getting?

Comment: Failed to create java virtual machine just by updating to Java 14 and starting my normal Eclipse. I have reverted back to Java 13.0.2.  This should be reported on Eclipse bugzilla https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/

Comment: I still have the same problem on version 8. and echo $JAVA_HOME is still empty.

Comment: You echo has the wrong quotes - back tick tries to execute code - it should be single quote.

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding JDK 14 as a runtime for Eclipse for now. Use 8 or 11.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60771575/2670892) for more details

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60970143/231397

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

If you can still reproduce the issue, execute:

```
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/MacOS
sudo ln -fs ../Home/lib/libjli.dylib
```

### More details

You had recent version of Oracle JDK 14. There is known bug with recent version of Oracle JDK or Open JDK: [JDK-8238225](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8238225). The issue has been reported also in Eclipse: [eclipse bug 559482](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=559482).

The issue will be fixed by next releases of JDK.

Meanwhile, the workaround differs depending of JDK version. I have done some experimentations to find generic solution. This one should always work:

```
cd $($(dirname $(readlink $(which javac)))/java_home)/../MacOS
sudo cp libjli.dylib libjli.dylib.bak
sudo ln -fs $(find ../Home -name libjli.dylib)
```

Answer (score -3):

Although not a solution to the problem. I ended up doing a factory reset. I know this won't help many people. However, it worked...