# Alert: "Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine"

Tags: java, eclipse

Running macOS 10.14.6 and I receive this error when trying to open Eclipse for Java EE Developers. I've tried basic things like reinstalling eclipse and the JDK I installed, updating java, and restarting but nothing works. I found posts on here saying to add a -vm line to eclipse.ini but I wasn't able to find the path that they use on my own laptop.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSTah.png

Comment: as per your screenshot, your machine should have java 1.8 else you get the above message.  [Java Installed on Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15826712/8035260)

Comment: Upon running the recommended line into terminal, I get this: **Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8".
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home** . I definitely have Java 1.8 installed as I can see it clearly in the system preferences.

Comment: type `which java` in terminal to show where it is installed. @airic

Comment: I am told `/usr/bin/java` and upon using it, I still get the same alert. When i use the `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home` however, I now get a **To open eclipse you need to install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime**.

Comment: don't install java se 6, it's just a [message](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation#Install_a_JVM). refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60771575/8035260

Comment: thank you! I was able to fix and open it by installing an older version

Comment: Eclipse does not currently work with Java 14 (this should be fixed by Java 14.0.1). Remove Java 14 and install Java 13.0.2 (or an older version).