# "Failed to create Java Virtual Machine"

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, virtual-machine

I have seen that are similar questions to mine however mine is not the same as it is partly different. Also I am getting into programming just now, so I really am not familiar with most of the technical terms. Let me explain:

I had installed Java from https://www.java.com/de/download/. I then started to install Eclipse. When I opened the Eclipse Installer, I received an error saying that I needed a JDK so I installed the latest one which was the version "Java SE 14". I then tried again to open the Eclipse Installer and got the error "Failed to create Java Virtual Machine". I did some research and read that "Java SE 14" was not compatible with Eclipse and therefore tried to delete Java completely and install it again. In my attempt to do so I went into the folder where "java" would reside and deleted everything. However when using the Terminal (java -version) it told me that java was still installed. I also tried to install "Java  SE 11" but I still get the same error.

I deleted something called a "bin" folder. The java.com page tells me that was bad as it is part of the system software. Am I in trouble now?

In my attempt to solve this by myself as a total beginner I feel like I messed up a lot of things. Is there a way to undo the damage? In the sense that I could delete all Java data and start new? I hope I made clear what problems I currently encounter.

Thanks in advance to anybody who is willing to help.

Comment: If macOS, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60771575/6505250

Comment: Yes but how do I switch to version before Java 14?

Comment: See the comment below the linked answer (Java 11 can be downloaded e.g. [here](https://adoptopenjdk.net/)).

Comment: Which `bin` folder? The `/bin` folder? **Yes**. Your mac is broken. The `$JAVA_HOME/bin` folder? Reinstall Java.

Comment: To remove Java 14 on macOS delete the whole of the `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk` directory