# How can I run eclipse properly?

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

Failed to create Java Virtual Machine:
[image: Failed to create Java Virtual Machine]

I've installed eclipse latest version with Java SE latest version
However, it keeps showing alerts that says "failed to create JVM"
How can I fix this??

Comment: Exactly what version of Java do you have? Is this macOS?

Comment: It's the macOS "sheet" UI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse Installation on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60765789/eclipse-installation-on-macos)

Comment: @nitind Yes, I was really assuming this is macOS. What I really want is the exact version of Java. Eclipse on macOS fails with the initial Java 14 release but is now OK with the Oracle 14.0.1 release

Comment: I've tried Java 14 but found out that it won't work so I uninstalled it and now I have Java 8 @greg-449

Comment: The initial Java 14 release did not work, Java 14.0.1 (Oracle release) works for me with Eclipse 2020-03