# Where to download JRE 1.8.0_172 for mac

Tags: java, runtime

I've googled for awhile now looking for JRE 1.8.0_172 (x64) for mac osx.

The oracle site only has 1.8.0_201 (https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html) for mac.

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look here. it might help you with the specific java version:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54254068/10683856