# Install Java with Brew without sudo

Tags: java, macos, homebrew

The question is possible duplicated from [How to install Java 8 on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342886/how-to-install-java-8-on-mac), however, it's not clear how to install the same package without sudo.

There is special option for `brew` to install in specific location `--appdir=~/Applications`. However, setting this doesn't work neither with `brew cask install --appdir=~/Applications <java 8 package>`, nor via `export HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS="--appdir=~/Applications"`.

Thanks.

Comment: JDK, or just JRE?  The Mac JRE is [available at Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html#JDK8) as a tar.gz file.  The JDK is [at AdoptOpenJDK.net](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html#x64_mac) as a tar.gz file.

Comment: @VGR So I can just place all source of java somewhere in my user space? That is it? Because in the linked issue, there is a solution with installing via `brew`. And it's not work for me (without sudo).

Comment: I honestly don’t know enough about `brew` to say whether it’s possible.  But a tar.gz is pretty easy to work with, so I figured I’d point out that there is an alternative.

Comment: `brew` doesn't require `sudo`. Have you installed `brew` follow the instructions on https://brew.sh.

Comment: @Kevin Not `brew`, but `brew` dependencies which I'm trying to install. Check the link with installing java 8.

Comment: You may check the permission settings of `~/Applications` by `ls -l`

Comment: @Kevin Thanks. As I mentioned it's my folder. No problem with it. Problem with `cask` package and java I think.

Comment: Got the same problem. And

`==> Package installers may write to any location; options such as --appdir are ignored.`

Comment: Solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65957215/1121571