# java 7 install on mac broken/ incomplete?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, java-7

I installed java 7 (both the JDK and the JRE) on a MAC (OSX 10.10.3). java preferences shows the installed version correctly (1.7.0_80) as does the output of "java -version". However it seems some path/ environment variables are not updated since /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions is still showing only up to 1.6 and not 1.7. Programs like Eclipse that are specifically looking for Java 7 or later in this path are hence failing to run.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267392/how-do-i-use-jdk-7-on-mac-osx

Comment: Wait, there is a JRE in JDK why did you installed both ? no need for that !

Comment: Can you make some screenshots ? like what is being shown in Java-version and Eclipse configuration ?

Comment: Java 7 (and 8) install in '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines'

Answer (score 0):

It's in a different location now: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`.

For instance, on my machine:

```
$ ls /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
1.4  1.4.2  1.5  1.5.0  1.6  1.6.0  A  Current  CurrentJDK

$ ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
jdk1.7.0_67.jdk  jdk1.8.0_20.jdk  jdk1.8.0_45.jdk
```