# Java not updating on OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: java, macos, osx-yosemite

Trying to execute selenium driver I found that I have an old version of Java. I downloaded the last version from java.com:
https://www.java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp
Everything went fine and I can see Java on my system preferences and it says is up to date.
Although if I run java -version on the command line i get:

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-466.1, mixed mode)
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Its pointing to the wrong installation i guess. what does `which java` output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24657630/3850595

Comment: @JordiCastilla tried to do that, but I don't get the 1.8 version in the list

Comment: that's because location in `OSX` changed from java 6 to next releases when distributor changed. **a)** Please check this [extended discussion in `SuperUser.com`](http://superuser.com/questions/490425/how-do-i-switch-between-java-7-and-java-6-on-os-x-10-8-2) and **b)** [Oracle installation docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html)

Comment: Guau, that seems quite complicated... I only need to update my java version from 1.6 to 1.8. Do I seriously have to go through to all that just to make it java 1.8 work?

Comment: Ho about just deleting the old JVM, system password required. Then install new one. That's what I've done many times.

Comment: @BasilBourque how do you uninstall the old one?

Comment: @petekaner Use the Finder to move it to the Trash. See [my Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10358228/642706) to a similar Question.

Comment: thanks! Would you post an answer with the solution? So we can close this :)